# Changing field status on django admin upon detail page

Tags: django, django-admin

I am very new to django admin feature.Here in my contact model I have a BooleanField called seen .In the django default admin when the user goes upon the detail page of the contact model I want to change the status of seen from `False` to `True`.But I didn't find any solutions with django admin.

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    sub = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    msg = models.TextField()
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

admin.py

```
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   readonly_fields = ['full_name','email','sub','msg','seen']
   list_filter = ['seen']
   search_fields = ['full_name']

admin.site.register(Contact,ContactAdmin)
```

Comment: You mark seen field as readonly_fields. remove it fraom readonly_fields array and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Overriding the `change_view` method which is the detail view. Here are the django reference/docs for overriding default admin views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
...

class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['full_name','email','sub','msg','seen']
    list_filter = ['seen']
    search_fields = ['full_name']

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, id=object_id)
        contact.seen = True
        contact.save()
        return super().change_view(
            request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
        )
admin.site.register(Contact,ContactAdmin)
```